# JQuery UI Datepicker loses focus when selecting date with mouse

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using JQuery ui with datepicker and when a user tabs on to a field, they appropriately get the calendar pop up.

1. User tabs (via  key onto field
2. User selects date with mouse click
3. User tabs
4. Tabindex starts over at one (at the beginning of form)

Here is code.  (May also have the tab index set)

```
<input type="text" name="demo" />
<input type="text" class="date" />
```

The jquery code is:

```
$(".date").datepicker();
```

Any suggestions on how I might go about solving this issue (bonus to shortest solution)?

Comment: Another solution that returns focus to the input field, but fixes IE so it doesn't reopen the calendar:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11121848/1469525

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Subscribe to the `onClose` or the `onSelect` event:

```
$("#someinput").datepicker(
{
    // other options goes here
    onSelect: function ()
    {
        // The "this" keyword refers to the input (in this case: #someinput)
        this.focus();
    }
});
```

Or in the case of `onClose`:

```
$("#someinput").datepicker(
{
    onClose: function ()
    {
        this.focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: both of these work, however the calendar drops down again.  Is there any quick solution around that?

Comment: If I could get it to focus on the next field...
onClose:function(){ focus on next field }  (Would Work).  Any suggestions?

Comment: -1: This trades one problem for another because it causes the calendar widget to re-appear.

Comment: -1: Neither of these cause focus to go back to the input field on Chrome 25.

Comment: If your calendar is set to only popup on "button" (showOn: "button") then this solutions works perfectly! 
@DanielAllenLangdon, this does not trade one problem for the next, your keyboard savvy user can continue to tab through to the next control and the calendar will close again. Without this solutions, your user has to manually focus the next control with the mouse. Basically, this solution solves the problem of the user having to refocus on selecting a date.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the suggestion Jeff, I modified your onSelect function to use the attribute filter to retrieve only elements with the tabindex specified by "nexttab".

```
$(function(){
  $(".date").datepicker({
      onSelect: function(){
          currenttab = $(el).attr("tabindex");
          nexttab = currenttab * 1 + 1;
          $("[tabindex='" + nexttab + "']").focus();
      }
  });
});
```

PS:
If you don't have tabindexes specified in your code, like I neglected to do earlier, simply add the following code:

```
$('input, select').each(function(i, val){
    $(this).attr('tabindex', i + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

See discussion about this problem at
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7266
with a solution at
http://jsfiddle.net/lankarden/9FtnW/

Comment: This particular solution only works in Chrome for me - in IE (I know, I know...) it results in a calendar that pops up twice.

Comment: -1: As of today, ticket 7266 has been closed as a duplicate of ticket 7765, but ticket 7765 is still an open bug with no solution. The idea of calling focus() is a problem in IE, where the calendar pops up again.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Jimmy's approach, but this sets the focus to the calendar icon (assuming your calender uses an icon), I found this way more appropriate when I had multiple date pickers next to each other.

Set the date default options so that they set focus to the icon when the calendar popup closes:

```
    $(".date").datepicker({
        onClose: function() {
            $(this).next('a').focus(); 
        }
    });
```

Add a  tag to the calendar icon so that it's focusable:

```
    $(".date").each(function() {
        $($(this).next('img')).wrap($("<A/>").attr("href","#"));
    });
```

Comment: +1: I like this solution because it appears to the user as though the focus is still on the input field they clicked on, rather than moving the focus to the next field, which is not the expected behavior. This works on Chrome 25, IE 9, Opera 12, Firefox 19, and Safari 5. Thanks!

Comment: I added the icon just so I could use this solution. It keeps the tab order without having to explicitly specify it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't care about the tab order, that is, not having it assigned so it follows the flow of the page, you could do something like this.

```
jQuery('.date').datepicker({
    'onSelect': function(){
        $(this).nextAll('input, button, textarea, a').filter(':first').focus();
    }
});
```

It works on the assumption that when the user selects the date, he is finished with that field and moves on to the next one, so it simply selects the next field.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the `onClose` event to return focus to your input when the datepicker closes, as `this` refers to the associated input field in that callback.  For example:

```
$('.date').datepicker({
   onClose: function() { this.focus(); }
});
```

Comment: This causes the calendar to pop up again in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Having it focus on the same box ultimately causes the date picker to pop back up and what we really want is for it to go to the next field.  Here is teh devised solution:

1. Requires the tabindex attribute to be set on your fields.
2. This is casting from a string to int in javascript (the * 1).
3. This actually moves the selected field to the next element, instead of the current focus

   > ```
   > $(function(){
   >   $(".date").datepicker({
   >       onSelect: function(){
   >           currenttab = $(this).attr("tabindex");
   >           nexttab = currenttab * 1 + 1;
   >           $(":input").each(function(){
   >               if ($(this).attr("tabindex") == nexttab)
   >                  $(this).focus();
   >           });
   >   }
   >   });
   > });
   > ```

Any suggestions to improve on this technique are appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes the element with the tabindex that equals "nexttab" may be hidden or otherwise unfocusable.  You should test to make sure $(this) can take focus.

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this problem as well and found that the given answers weren't exactly what I was looking for. Here is what I did.

A [blog](http://jqueryminute.com/set-focus-to-the-next-input-field-with-jquery/) mentioned a jQuery function that would allow you to select the next form element on the screen. I imported that into my project and called it onClose of the datepicker dialog.

In case the link goes dead, here is the function

```
$.fn.focusNextInputField = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var fields = $(this).parents('form:eq(0),body').find('button,input,textarea,select');
        var index = fields.index( this );
        if ( index > -1 && ( index + 1 ) < fields.length ) {
            fields.eq( index + 1 ).focus();
        }
        return false;
    });
};
```

Then simply called it onClose of the datepicker

```
$(this).datepicker({
    onClose: function () {
       $(this).focusNextInputField();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the focus to the next input field after pressing enter (which selects todays date by default) or when clicking a date from the calendar by using this

```
$(".jqDateField").datepicker('option', {
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/y', onClose: function () {
        $(':input:eq(' + ($(':input').index(this) + 1) + ')').focus();
    }
});
```

This may be required to set focus on the next text input incase you have a select or an input button in the "way"

```
$(':input[type="text"]:eq(' + ($(':input[type="text"]').index(this) + 1) + ')')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added an empty href tag  next to the datepicker input control and focus onto it in the onClose event handler. This solved my problem of the focus shifting all the way to the top of the page when the calendar was closed. I am using that href tag to display error messages; therefore it serves two purposes for me.