# jQuery UI datepicker give focus to the input without loading the calendar again in IE?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-datepicker

I know that jQuery UI datepicker loses focus if the date is selected with a mouse. I want to able to give focus to that input field. So I did something like this

```jquery
$("#patientDob").live("click", function() {
$("#patientDob").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {  
        this.focus();           
        // selecting a date moves the page, so remove the href attribute            
        $(".ui-datepicker a").removeAttr("href"); 
    },  
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    duration: 'fast',
    showOn: 'focus' 
}).focus();
});
```

This does gives the focus to the input field, but in IE it keeps on loading the calendar again. It does not do that in Firefox or Chrome.
How can I be able to give focus to the input field without loading the calendar again and again in IE?

Also, if I make a input field readonly and after selecting the date in IE the field loses focus and if I try to press backspace it takes me to the previously visited page.

Comment: so, you have the datepicker showOn a fucus event, and you have the input get focus when they click the datepicker. of course it's gonna do that. why are you doing that? if they click the datepicker, they are using the datepicker not the input. the only other option is to have the datepicker only appear when they click a datepicker button instead of on focus.

Comment: i do that because the input field for the datepicker is loaded thorugh ajax. i need a way to set up datepicker on the input field

Answer (score 3):

My solution uses the beforeShow event to cancel the show for IE (since it seems to work okay without the hack in Chrome and Firefox). The onSelect and onClose set a flag before returning focus to the input box. See my full write-up to [also send blur and change events](http://www.objectpartners.com/2012/06/18/jquery-ui-datepicker-ie-focus-fix/) if you need those.

```
$("input.dateInput").datepicker({            
   /* fix buggy IE focus functionality */
   fixFocusIE: false,

   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
       this.fixFocusIE = true;
       $(this).focus();
   },
   onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
       this.fixFocusIE = true;
       this.focus();
   },
   beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
       var result = $.browser.msie ? !this.fixFocusIE : true;
       this.fixFocusIE = false;
       return result;
   }
});
```

Comment: shouldn't the second `this.focus();` be `$(this).focus();`?

Comment: [also posted to your full write-up].  By isolation, I have an issue with the beforeShow event code.  In a form with 2 fields that use the calendar picker, the filed that includes the beforeShow statement ends up being disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you. To solve it I override the following methods of datepicker:

```
$.datepicker._attachments = function(input, inst) {
    var appendText = $.datepicker._get(inst, "appendText");
    var isRTL = $.datepicker._get(inst, "isRTL");

    if (inst.append) {
        inst.append.remove();
    }
    if (appendText) {
        inst.append = $('<span class="' + $.datepicker._appendClass + '">' + appendText + "</span>");
        input[isRTL ? "before" : "after"](inst.append);
    }
    input.unbind("focus", $.datepicker._showDatepicker);
    if (inst.trigger) {
        inst.trigger.remove();
    }
    var showOn = $.datepicker._get(inst, "showOn");
    if (showOn == "focus" || showOn == "both") {
        input.focus($.datepicker._showDatepicker);
    }
    if (showOn == "button" || showOn == "both") {
        var buttonText = $.datepicker._get(inst, "buttonText");
        var buttonImage = $.datepicker._get(inst, "buttonImage");
        inst.trigger = $($.datepicker._get(inst,"buttonImageOnly") ? $("<img/>")
                .addClass($.datepicker._triggerClass).attr({
                    src : buttonImage,
                    alt : buttonText,
                    title : buttonText
                })
                : $('<button type="button"></button>')
                .addClass($.datepicker._triggerClass)
                .html('<span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-icon-calendar"></span><span class="ui-button-text">ui-button</span>'));
        input[isRTL ? "before" : "after"](inst.trigger);
        inst.trigger.click(function() {
            if ($.datepicker._datepickerShowing
                    && $.datepicker._lastInput == input[0]) {
                $.datepicker._hideDatepicker();
            } else {
                $.datepicker._showDatepicker(input[0]);
            }
            return false;
        });

        input.bind('focus', function(e) {
            if (!$.datepicker._datepickerShowing) {
                inst.trigger.trigger('click');
            }
        });

        input.bind('click', function(e) {
            input.trigger('focus');
        });
    }
};


$.datepicker._selectDate = function(id, dateStr) {
    var target = $(id);
    var inst = $.datepicker._getInst(target[0]);
    dateStr = (dateStr != null ? dateStr : $.datepicker._formatDate(inst));
    if (inst.input) {
        inst.input.val(dateStr);
    }
    $.datepicker._updateAlternate(inst);
    var onSelect = $.datepicker._get(inst, "onSelect");
    if (onSelect) {
        onSelect.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0]
        : null), [ dateStr, inst ]);
    } else {
        if (inst.input) {
            inst.input.trigger("change");
        }
    }
    if (inst.inline) {
        $.datepicker._updateDatepicker(inst);
    } else {
        if ($.datepicker._datepickerShowing) {
            inst.input.select();
        }
        setTimeout("$.datepicker._hideDatepicker()", 10);

        $.datepicker._lastInput = inst.input[0];
        $.datepicker._lastInput = null;
    }
};
```

Check if it works for you...

Answer (score -1):

call datepicker at document.ready event