# jQuery datepicker focus after click day of month

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am noticing that jQuery datepicker is neither activating the current element nor the next element in the tab index after tabbing into a field spawns a datepicker instance and the mouse is used to click on a day.

```
<input type="text" id="no1" />
<input type="text" id="no2" />
<input type="text" id="no3" />

$('#no2').datepicker();
$('#no1').focus();
```

If you check out http://jsfiddle.net/DgkJZ/1/

and tab to the second field, click a date, you'll see what I mean about the tab focus going nowhere.  Is there some way around this that doesn't involve editing jQuery UI source?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401917/jquery-ui-datepicker-loses-focus-when-selecting-date-with-mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to catch the `onSelect` and set focus accordingly

```
$('#no2').datepicker( {
    onSelect: function() {
       $('#no3').focus();
    }
);
```